# Python's httplib HTTPSConnection doesn't appear to pass parameters in a post request

Tags: python, httplib

I am running the following code on an endpoint

```
def get(method, url, endpoint, params={}):
    headers = {"Authorization" : get_auth()}
    h = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url)
    params_encoded = urllib.urlencode(params)
    print params_encoded
    h.request(method, endpoint, params_encoded, headers)
    return h.getresponse()
```

and it doesn't seem to pass the parameters to the request. The same exact request works perfectly fine via curl.

I see answers on SO that this works for an HTTPConnection, though. I was wondering if I am actually doing anything incorrectly or if there is a bug with HTTPConnection or maybe something else is not working properly?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

Here is what `get_auth` looks like:

```
def get_auth():
    pw = get_password()
    auth = ('%s:%s' % (USERNAME, pw)).encode('base64').strip()
    return 'Basic %s' % auth
```

Comment: Do you have to use `httplib`? It is easier with `urllib2` or `httplib2`. Even easier with a third party HTTP library named `requests`.

Comment: It looks correct, for temporary debugging (make sure all vars are correct) try `print "-"*40, "\n" vars(locals()), "\n\", "-"*40`

Comment: @ozgur agree with using requests, Ken R. really streamlined http with that library

Comment: @ozgur I don't have to use httplib. Let me try it with httplib2.

Comment: @ozgur @David `requests` worked just fine! Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: @ozgur You deleted your answer, but I actually thought there were helpful bits in there. I was also leaving a comment answering one of your questions. Can you undelete it?

Comment: Maybe for the next person that stumbles upon this question.

Comment: I deleted it because there was nothing wrong with `get_auth()`. I need more information from you such as the error message and what other headers you are adding. The problem was probably due to lack of adding `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` value to the header which is automatically added by the requests library.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Yeah, I was going to say that there was no error being returned. The server was behaving as if no parameters had been passed in. I was not including this header. Let me see if that works.

Comment: @ozgur Hm, no, that didn't help either. Oh well. `requests` is great and I'll use that instead.